# Esp32 and Site communication

Tags: html, local, lamp, esp32

Basically, i have a esp32 with a local ip i can turn it on and off a lamp by typping "http:192.168.1.52/L" or "/H" cuz im in the same network as the esp32.
is it possible for a button click on a webpage makes the server access the ip address with the /H or /L and turn on and off the light? like: friend->myOpenServer->localEsp32
my friend having access to a html hosted in my local network that access the esp32 ip

Comment: check for esp32 LED blink examples in arduino IDE. it should solve the requirement you want

Comment: If its not the same network...you would need something like MQTT.

Comment: @AbhishekDK...really? How exactly is the blink LED example similar?

Comment: will look into mqtt, heard from a friend they used it at work for similar stuff

Answer (score 0):

you can add the buttons via CSS in WiFiClient println methods as shown below
you can make appropriate changes to your need

```
        WiFiClient client = server.available();


        client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
        client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
        client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");

        client.println("<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}");
        client.println(".button { background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px;");
        client.println("text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}");
        client.println(".button2 {background-color: #555555;}</style></head>");
        
        // Web Page Heading
        client.println("<body><h1>ESP32 Web Server</h1>");
```

Comment: will try it out later today!

Comment: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-web-server-arduino-ide/